# Let $A,B \in M(n,F)$ be such that $AB=BA$. Then show that $A$ and $B$ has same characteristic polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A,B \in M(n,F)$ be such that $AB=BA$. Then show that $A$ and $B$ has same characteristic polynomial.

How can I proceed to this? If I take $|B||\lambda I-A|=|\lambda B- BA|= |\lambda B- AB|$ But this will not help me..

Comment: What do you mean by $|B|$?

Comment: Maybe you've been asked to prove that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same characteristic polynomial (of course $AB=BA$ is not required, or the problem would be trivial).

Comment: That is true and the proof I know. anyway I should think about counter example sorry

Answer (score 4):

This is not true. Take $M(2,\mathbb R)$ and 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
and $B$ any other matrix with eigenvalues other than $1$. For instance, 
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&3\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Yeah Sorry. The example should be derived by me. The question is wrong..